# Imagem em JavaScript não aparece

Tags: javascript, html5

Porque as imagens não estão aparecendo quando eu clico no botão? Eu as chamei via JavaScript, ela faz faz parte de um botão que serve para mutar e desmutar meu vídeo. Quando eu clico não aparece as imagens, segue o código.

#### HTML:

```
<div id="buttonbar">
     <button id="volDn"><img src="images/video/menos.png" id="menos"/></button>
     <button id="volUp"><img src="images/video/mais.png" id="btn-mais"/></button>
     <button id="mute"><img src="images/video/som.png" id="btn-mudo"/></button>
</div>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
function init() {
var video = document.getElementById("Video1");
if (video.canPlayType) {
    document.getElementById("buttonbar").style.display = "inline";

    function setVol(value) {
        var vol = video.volume;
        vol += value;
        if (vol >= 0 && vol <= 1) {
            video.volume = vol;
        } else {

            video.volume = (vol < 0) ? 0 : 1;
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("volDn").addEventListener("click", function () {
        setVol(-.1); // down by 10%
    }, false);

    document.getElementById("volUp").addEventListener("click", function () {
        setVol(.1);  // up by 10%
    }, false);

    document.getElementById("mute").addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
        if (video.muted) {
            video.muted = false;
            evt.target.innerHTML = "<img alt='volume on button' src='../images/video/mutado.png' />"
        } else {
            video.muted = true;
            evt.target.innerHTML = "<img alt='volume off button' src='../images/video/desmutado.png' />"
        }
    }, false);
}
            video.muted = true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Os caminhos das imagens no js estão relativos, diferentes dos presentes no HTML.

Creio que mudando:

```
<img alt='volume on button' src='../images/video/mutado.png' id='js-imagem' />
```

Para:

```
<img alt='volume on button' src='images/video/mutado.png' id='js-imagem' />
```

Resolve o problema.

Comment: ele aprece normalmente funcionou porem quando eu clico de volta a imagem que estava antes não volta

Comment: será q nao é pq ta usando a "desmutado" ao invés de "som"?

Comment: então e que e assim essas duas imagens são uma para o som desmutado e uma com o som mutado mais ai assim eu fiz o código que você postou e deu certo porem quando eu clico de volta o botão não volta fica no desmutado e queria que quando clica-se também volta-se para o mutado. Resumidamente eu clico ele muda porem se clico de novo ele não volta ao padrão de antes

Comment: Foi o que o @MichelSimões disse, você está usando o arquivo `images/video/desmutado.png` ou invés de `images/video/som.png`